# Stripe Checkout - How to pass a value to merchant's server code?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Stripe Checkout calls PHP server code on my website after the customer completes the Stripe charge form, which is in turn called from my order form.

I'd like to pass some of the order form information, such as the customer name, through to my server code, but adding a line like

```
<input type=hidden id="nsr_name" value="Adam Baker" />
```

after the script options fails to pass a value.

ADDED 11/28/17:

It works! One can pass strings from the Stripe Checkout client form to your payment server code as follows:

```
<form action="<?=$FormServer?>" method="POST">
<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="keytoken"
    data-amount="2200"
    data-name="Company Name"
    data-description="description"
    data-allow-remember-me="false"
    data-image="logo.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="USD"
    data-zip-code="false"
    >
    </script>
<input type=hidden name="data_name" value="Adam Baker" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but need to [specify a `name` property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) instead of (or in addition to) an `id`. This would look something like:

```
<input type=hidden name="nsr_name" value="Adam Baker" />
```

This isn't a Stripe specific thing, but rather a question of how HTML forms work.